# Networking (classmate like) website database model

Tags: database-design, network

I am working  on a project that consists in building a networking website like [the Classmate web site](http://www.classmates.com/).

I have proposed a database model based on the social media database model presented on the databaseanswers.org web site.

Does my database model match perfectly with my business rules? The rules are:

> - A provinces has one or many towns
> - A primary school belongs to a town
> - A high school belongs to a town
> - An institute belongs to a town
> - A university belongs to a town
> - A university or an institute has one or many departments
> - A university has one or many faculties
> - A university could have at least one or no institute
> - An institute could belong or not to a university; in the latter case it is independent
> - A person lives in a town located in a state
> - A person was born in a town located in a state
> - A person holds up to one user account
> - A user account attended a primary school or a high school or an institute or a university or an enterprise
> - A user account stores none or many messages
> - A user account sends or receives none or many messages
> - There are many types of messages
> - One user account could have a relationship (friend, colleague, classmate, ...) with another
> - There are many types of relationships
> - At registration an account could choose a primary school or a high school or an institute or a university or an enterprise
> - An account that has already chosen a primary school or a high school or an institute or a university or an enterprise can choose one or many more later
> - An account could display another account information
> - An account could display the list of its friends (relationship)
> - An account could display the list of the photos it has uploaded on the web site
> - An account could display the list of the photos related to the school it has attended or the enterprise it has worked in
> - An account could invite another account to be in relationship; the other account could accept or refuse the invitation.
> - An account could seek for its relationship
> - The administrator should be able to list all the persons' and all the users' accounts
> - The administrator should be able to list all the schools an account has attended
> - An account and the administrator could update the list of schools an account has attended

[image]

Comment: Your question is very broad - maybe you should try and get some sort of system together and then, if you run into problems, get back to us. At first glance, your schema **appears** to be **OK**. However, with a system this large, a 10,000m overview won't really cut the mustard. One thing I did notice is that you have no link between Town and Institute (use singular names for tables - this is an opinion, but at the very least you should be consistent, either all singular or all plural).